# setup apache www directory for multiple users over sftp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, user-permissions

I have standard Ubuntu 16.04 droplet over digitalocean with LAMP stack.
By default I have one user with root privileges (for admin use). I access any directory from root through ssh like with filezilla or netbeans. It all works fine as it should upto this.

I need more users created so that I can configure them to be able to access a particular vhost directory say like `/var/www/html/domain2.com`  or probably only `/var/www/html/*`

Also I need to be sure that doing so will not affect any Apache related permissions on folders and files. Say if I create a folder say uploads from user1 and www-data user cant read or write into that folder uploads.

How can I do this ?

Comment: @JennyD it doesnt help anything about apache and permissions

Comment: That helps much better @AndrewSchulman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mount the directory they need to access with [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/) in their home directory

ex : `bindfs -u user1 -g user1 --create-for-user=www-data --create-for-group=www-data /home/user1/www/ var/www/html/domain2.com`

Comment: Thanks looks good enough. I will give this a try tomorrow and will update you.